# Harmonic Oscillator with Fourier Transform (again)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-transform

The equation to be solved still is given by: $$m\,\ddot{x} + D\,x = 0$$ what can be easily resolved for $x$ using characteristic polynomials or other techniques customized for homogenous differential equations. I just ask myself whether there exist also an elegant way using Fourier Transform. Some of these steps have been unrolled in an equal question regarding this method but some of them are still unclear to me:

First of applying FT: $x(t) \to \hat{x}(\omega)$: $$-m\omega^2\,\hat{x}(\omega)+ D\,\hat{x}(\omega) = 0$$

Now usually this can be changed into an equation for $\hat{x}(\omega)$ solely on one side that can be inverse Fourier transformed but in this case I only get $\hat{x}(\omega) = 0$ what is kind of leading to nowhere. Any escape?

Comment: You get a more general solution, as the value at roots of the factors is not determined and the Fourier transform has to be treated as a generalized function, $\hat x(ω)=A\delta(ω-ω_0)+B\delta(ω+ω_0)$ where $-mω_0^2+D=0$.

Comment: The Fourier Transform is appropriate for problems on the whole real line. On the half line $t\ge 0$ the Laplace Transform is the appropriate one.

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't heard of these exceptions.  Is there a general prompt describing these phenomena?